# Can members of a derived class can be accessed when its casted to base class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance, polymorphism, backgroundworker

I put up an simple example to illustrate my question. Here is the base class.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>

class Task
{
public:
    Task()
    {
        Empty.store(true);
    }
    std::mutex Access;
    std::atomic<bool> Empty;
    virtual void Work() = 0;
};
```

This is the derived class.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

class ExampleTask : public Task
{
public:
    void Work()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        {
            Data[i] = rand();
        }
    }
private:
    int Data[16];
};
```

As you can see, this example is about tasks or jobs which will be done asynchronously. Imagine, there is a queue of `Task`s to do and a bunch of worker threads, maybe one for each CPU core on the target machine.

The task queue stores the tasks casted to their base class, so that the worker threads can just pick up the next job from the queue and call `Work()`.

```
std::list<Task*> Queue;

ExampleTask *example = new ExampleTask();
Queue.push_back((Task*)example);
```

A worker thread would then fetch the first task, remove it from the queue, and work on it.

```
while(true)
{
    Task *current = Queue.front();
    Queue.erase(Queue.begin());
    current->Work();
}
```

Would this concept work? Can `Data` be accessed when `current->Work()` is called, even if I deal with a pointer to the base class?

Comment: Yes this works, welcome to polymorphism :) And you don't even need a cast in `Queue.push_back((Task*)example);`. These conversions are implicit.

Comment: @jrok Does this imply that I could take any class from a third party library, inherit from it and overwrite some functions, cast the instanced object back to the base class, and let the library use it without knowing?

Comment: That works as long as you are overwriting virtual methods.

Comment: If the base class is designed for that (has virtual functions that can be overriden), yes. That's the whole the point of [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: But note that you do not need to cast back to anything.

Comment: Okay, that's basically how interfaces in C++ work, right? :-)

Comment: @MaxBeikirch, _overriding_ not overwriting

Comment: Thanks to you all. @jrok Could you write a short answer so that I can accept it? Because you were the first providing an answer.

Comment: @jrok Alright, I'll do so, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**: A reference/pointer to a base class can be implicitly converted to a pointer/reference to a derived class. This is exactly how [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) and static polymorphism works:

```
template<typename T>
struct CRTP_base
{
    void execute()
    {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->f(); //The instance is casted to the known derived class, and we use the derived class function f.
    }
};

struct Foo : public CRTP_base<Foo>
{
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "Wow, compile-time resolved polymorphism!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   Foo my_foo_instance;
   CRTP_base<Foo>& base_reference = my_foo_instance;
   base_reference.execute();
};
```

This prints:

> Wow, compile-time resolved polymorphism!

[Here](http://ideone.com/51iPnq) is a running example.